# Function like C# Array.Copy() in the C language

Tags: c#, c

I'm looking for a C function similar to the C# Array.Copy().
I found memcpy() only, but I need to copy from specific index too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an array like this:

```
SomeType myArray[50];
```

And you want to copy elements indexed 19-29 (the 20th through 30th elements).

Then you do:

```
memcpy(dest, &myArray[19], 10 * sizeof(SomeType));
```

*Note:  this code-segment makes no provision for initializing `myArray`, or allocating memory to `dest`*

Answer (score 3):

`memcpy` is all you have.  If you want to copy specific ranges, it's something like this:

```
memcpy(dst, &src[i_start], num_to_copy * sizeof(*src));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pointer arithmetic.  It's evil, but in C, it's your friend.